# Get index of each component in Svelte slot

Tags: listview, material-design, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Is there a way to loop through all the children in a Svelte component?

### Goal

I'm working on creating a list component in Svelte with this syntax (ideally).

```
<List>
  <ListItem>Item 1</ListItem>
  <ListItem>Item 2</ListItem>
  <ListItem>Item 3</ListItem>
</List>
```

However, the list should have quite a bit of interactivity.

- Users should be able to click on an item and select it
- Only the first item should be tabbable (`tabindex={0}`)
- Users should be able to use arrow keys / enter key to select a list item
- +more that's not relevant to the question

Check out the [Material Design web components for demos](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/list).

### Issue

To do this, elements need to know their "position" in the list. For instance, the first list item needs to know that it's the first to set the correct `tabindex`. And to use arrow keys to navigate the list, you need to know "Item 2 is active" to switch to "Item 3" on arrow down.

Is there a way to loop through all the children in a component?

Or alternatively, a way to achieve the Material Design list behavior through composition?

*I know it's possible to achieve this by using a data prop instead of composition. But for my use case, composition will likely be much better in the long run.*

### React equivalent

If you're familiar with React, I looking for something that works like this incredibly simplified example.

```
const List = (props) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {React.Children.forEach(props.children, (child, index) => (
        child.props.tabIndex = index === 0 ? 0 : -1
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

const ListItem = (props) => {
  return <li tabIndex={props.tabIndex}>{props.children}</li>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a register function in the parent (your List component) for a pulldown menu component.

Something like:

List component:

```
  function nested(nestedText, clicked = false) {
    if (clicked) {
      // clicked and then do something
      ...
    } else {
      // register listItem
      register = [...register, nestedText];
      return register.length - 1;  // itemIdx
    }
  }
  setContext('nested', nested);
```

Item component:

```
let text, itemIdx, thisObj;
const nested = getContext('nested');

onMount(() => {
  text = thisObj.textContent;
  itemIdx = nested(text);  // register item
  ...
});
```

Item component html:

```
<a
  href="..."
  target="..."
  on:click|stopPropagation="{() => {
     nested(text, true);
  }}"
  bind:this={thisObj}>
  <slot />
</a>
```